# Unsupported Operand Types for /: 'str' and 'float'

Tags: python-2.7, bioinformatics, scikit-learn

I'm having a bit of trouble with understanding this error message here...

I have been using the sklearn machine learning tools on some of my data recently. I've tried outputting the Silhouette coefficient for my data, using the following code below:

```
distmat = []
for row in distmat_csv:
    distmat.append(row[1:])
in_distmat.close()

distmat_array = np.array(distmat, dtype=object)
print distmat_array


out_metricsfile = open('Influenza A All Subtypes Human Strains %s in %s Clustering Metrics.txt' % (name1, name2), 'w+') 
out_metricsfile.write('%s in %s Clustering Metrics \n' % (name1, name2))
out_metricsfile.write('Estimated number of clusters: %d \n' % n_clusters)
out_metricsfile.write("Silhouette Coefficient: %0.3f \n"
      % metrics.silhouette_score(distmat_array, labels, metric='precomputed'))
out_metricsfile.close()
```

The distmat array is just a series of numbers which I read from a CSV file. It looks something like this:

```
[[0.000000 0.614841 0.613074 ..., 0.007067 0.007067 0.010601]
 [0.614841 0.000000 0.012367 ..., 0.616608 0.613074 0.611307]
 [0.613074 0.012367 0.000000 ..., 0.614841 0.611307 0.609541]
 ..., 
 [0.007067 0.616608 0.614841 ..., 0.000000 0.010601 0.014134]
 [0.007067 0.613074 0.611307 ..., 0.010601 0.000000 0.010601]
 [0.010601 0.611307 0.609541 ..., 0.014134 0.010601 0.000000]]
```

The error message that gets returned looks as such:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script9-perform-affinity-propagation-and-display.py", line 92, in <module>
    % metrics.silhouette_score(distmat_array, labels, metric='precomputed'))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.13.1-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/sklearn/metrics/cluster/unsupervised.py", line 84, in silhouette_score
    return np.mean(silhouette_samples(X, labels, metric=metric, **kwds))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.13.1-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/sklearn/metrics/cluster/unsupervised.py", line 146, in silhouette_samples
    for i in range(n)])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.13.1-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/sklearn/metrics/cluster/unsupervised.py", line 176, in _intra_cluster_distance
    a = np.mean(distances_row[mask])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 2374, in mean
    return mean(axis, dtype, out)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'
```

I'm stuck at understanding the error message. How do I know where I've gone wrong? And if anybody is kind enough, where did I go wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... so I actually figured out where the problem lay. By changing "dtype" from 'object' to 'float', the problem was solved...